# Error 0x80004003 during VS 2017 RC install

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm running Windows 10, no pending updates, I've run sfc /scan now and DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth neither of which reported issues.  I've tried installing enterprise, professional and community and built the local installer with the --layout flag for professional all of which produce the same error.  I have also tried uninstalling visual studio 2015 enterprise and a variety of other visual studio bits, resharper and ncrunch.

```
[3604:0011][2016-11-19T11:06:58] Error 0x80004003: 
   0x80004003 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.InstanceRepository.GetInstance()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.<GetInstances>d__25.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.VerifyInstallationPath(IServiceProvider services, String installationPath, IInstance instance, IQuery query)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From [this comment](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/10/05/announcing-visual-studio-15-preview-5/):

> After many times of trying to install the new preview, I at last managed to set it down in my computer. Here I share what I have done.
>
> First you must uninstall the installed Microsoft Visual Studio Installer from the Control Panel — Programms–Uninstall Or Modify Programs
>
> Then delete the installed files related to the preview version of VisualStudio15 in the following folders:
>
> 1. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 2. C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio
> 3. %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
>
> Download and install the vs_Enterprise.exe
>
> When complete downloading files needed, you can install them, then you see the visual studio IDE

Comment: I wasn't clearing AppData or ProgramData during my previous attempts.  I had to also delete the packages and setup folders from AppData/../VisualStudio, but it's working now.  Thanks!

Comment: I also had to delete C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\ _Instances

Comment: Thanks! Works for me!

Comment: That worked for me too! @vivainio's comment should be included in the post too, I had to delete that folder to it work for me.

Comment: You don't know how many lives you saved with this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I've also had this problem, but I noticed that if you go to *%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe* and run that (in command prompt as Admin with `-full`) and then reinstall, everything works great. If you already removed that directory you can just launch the installer but instead of *choose products* you just close it again, and then you can go to folder above and run the `InstallCleanup.exe -full`.  In my case this happened when my computer died in the middle of the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

1) uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio from the Control Panel
2) delete C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
3) delete C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Visual Studio\Setup
4) delete C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Visual Studio\Packages

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me in the end. A complete uninstall and reinstall.