# Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition Installation Failure

Tags: visual-studio

I am really struggling to get VS 2017 Community Edition to install successfully on my laptop.

The installer runs but after making my selection of components and clicking install, it fails. The log shows the error code - 0x80004003. After checking this code, I followed the suggestion given in Stackoverflow "Error 0x80004003 during VS 2017 RC install" by removing the installer, folders, and the files in the AppData folder. This made absolutely NO DIFFERENCE. It will still NOT INSTALL. I have checked the free HD size and there is a good 21GB free.

Output from log:

[27ac:000e][2016-12-10T17:28:30] Error 0x80004003: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.InstanceRepository.GetInstance()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.d__25.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.VerifyInstallationPath(IServiceProvider services, String installationPath, IInstance instance, IQuery query)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Does anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 0x80004003 during VS 2017 RC install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699930/error-0x80004003-during-vs-2017-rc-install)

Comment: No this is NOT a duplicate and it is clear that you have not read the question clearly and understood it

Comment: Any details regarding your OS version?  Other software/hardware details?

Comment: Running Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I found a zombie VS2015 install process. Reboot or unlock K:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages{_instances|_bootstrap}. Installs like a charm now.

Comment: VS2017 on Windows 7 pro 64 bit

Answer (score -2):

I had to reset Windows 10 Anniversary Framework to target x86 x64 applications and also to repair the Framework installer. Somehow or other updates had caused a problem where I was constantly getting a generic CLR error which didn't really mean much.  Once I corrected this, the Microsoft instructions for downloading and creating an offline installer worked perfectly for the total package which included all workloadds.