# Visual Studio 2017 RC Setup Operation Failed

Tags: visual-studio, installation, ide, development-environment

I first tried to install VS 2017 RC and a problem occurred during installation. I tried to repair the installation but while it was repairing - my computer blue screened (probably unrelated to installation I was running a lot of programs). Now, whenever I try to install VS 2017 - it instantly gives me this error log and says 'Setup operation failed'. What do I do to fix this?

Error log:

> [29cc:0004][2016-12-22T07:39:53] Error 0x80004003: 
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.InstanceRepository.GetInstance()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.d__27.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.VerifyInstallationPath(IServiceProvider services, String installationPath, IInstance instance, IQuery query)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I tried posting on VS developer community but it is instantly marked as duplicated and linked to other duplicates which link to other duplicates which have no solution.

Comment: This is the solution to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699930/error-0x80004003-during-vs-2017-rc-install

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Refer to the error message, you can try to remove the existing VS 2017 RC that install failed before as below:

1. Go to Control Panel—Programs and Features, if there has ‘Microsoft Visual Studio 2017’, right click it and choose ‘Uninstall’
2. Try to delete the following installed folders: (you can back up those folders before any modification, in case we need to roll back)

•   Go to the folder: %ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio and delete the ‘Packages’ folder and ‘Setup’ folder if there has.

•   Go to the Visual Studio installation folder (normally under %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio) and delete the folder ‘2017’

After that, make sure windows update is up-to-date, clean up the %temp% folder and temporarily disable any antivirus software, reboot the computer and re-run the VS 2017 RC installer as administrator again.

Comment: The installation is actually starting now, thanks! Been pulling my hair out deleting various files and programs related to Visual studio and nothing working.

Comment: I think %temp%  -folder was the root of the problem on my install. Thank you very much for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

A common problem is that when you go to the downloads page it automatically downloads the x64 version of VS. So, create a Dev account (free) then go to downloads from the dev homepage and select the version you want to download and check x86. Hope this helps!