# Cannot install Visual Studio 2017 community edition after sudden shutdown

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017, reinstall

I started installing VS and then my computer turned off suddenly (due to overheating).

When I was reinstalling it, an error message appeared saying:

```
Can't install in a non empty folder.
```

So I deleted the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\community

Then, when I tried to install it, it failed.

This is the log:

> [2a18:0008][2017-06-09T09:08:50] Error 0x80004003:     at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.InstanceRepository.GetInstance()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Cache.CacheRepository.d__28.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 predicate)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.VerifyInstallationPath(IServiceProvider
>   services, String installationPath, IInstance instance, IQuery query)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String
>   destination, CancellationToken token)Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the error message, you can try to completely remove the installed VS 2017 as below:

1. Go to Control Panel-Programs and Features, right click the VS 2017 and ‘Uninstall’
2. Manually remove or delete the VS 2017 installation folders: *%ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages* and *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\community*

Please have a look at this similar issue: [Visual Studio 2017 RC Setup Operation Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278054/visual-studio-2017-rc-setup-operation-failed/)

Answer (score 5):

Go to your folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\community`
Make sure this folder is Empty. There shouldn't be any other directory inside, then check your error has been gone and Install button is enabled.

Answer (score -2):

Just create a new directory and delete the corrupted one. Go to the folder location where visual studio will be installed which is in programs (x86) I believe and create a new directory in Microsoft Visual Studio, then on installation wizard just select the folder you created!

good luck. hope this helped