# I have installed VS 2017. But the installer can't find it, which results in that I can't update and uninstall them

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

This is my Visual Studio UI and installer:

Then, I try to open the installer from Visual Studio. But it shows an error message:

I think that there is no specific path of the vs in its config files. However, I failed to find it. Please share your advice and a solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: If there is any information which you could add to your question *as text* instead of an image, that could make it easier for us to help you find an answer.

Comment: I don't know why I can't upload the image.

Comment: It show me a popup on which there is a sentence "Missing option value:installPath";

Comment: 1) It is not clear to me if you are trying to install Visual Studio or if you have created an installer project and that is what is not working, please would you tell us which one. 2) If the upload image file size is too big, it won't work. Also, it might not work if the image is on some file upload sites. It should work with imgur.com.

Comment: The installer thinks I haven't installed VS. So,when I open it, I only see install button of three different editions. I open the program uninstall in the control panel and click uninstall vs. Then installer show "Installation error,unable to find the product that matches the following parameters "+ path of my vs;

Comment: If you have customised your VS then you should make a backup of its settings ("Tools" menu -> "Import and Export Settings..."). If the answers at [Visual Studio 2017 Broken and Cannot Uninstall or Repair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375811/visual-studio-2017-broken-and-cannot-uninstall-or-repair) do not help, then use something like Revo Uninstaller to uninstall VS.

Comment: You cannot upload images simply because you have not enough reputation. You need to then type the exact error message (word by word).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this way
- Open CMD with admin privilage and go to this path

`cd /d c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\installer`

Depend on which version of visual studio you have installed (Enterprise, Community or Professional) type :

for **Enterprise**

```
vs_installershell.exe repair --installPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise"
```

for **Community**

```
vs_installershell.exe repair --installPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
```

for **Professional**

```
vs_installershell.exe repair --installPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional"
```

here is the source it has worked for some users

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/313423/missing-option-value-installpath.html