# Manually download missing package for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

When installing visual studio if we already have deleted content of `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` directory then whole setup process will be turned into a real nightmare constantly complaining about missing packages. I've searched the web for a solution and the only working one I've found is a tool called `install and uninstall troubleshooter`.but the problem with it is i have to interrupt setup process and use this tool to remove the package and then get back to setup again which is really cumbersome job to do.
But the good thing is for every package that visual studio fails to uninstall it logs a `GUID` like this `{A2999714-5C2C-3729-A911-4AE198B7B2FD}` in the log file.Now better and ideal solution in my mind is looking after an official website from which i be able to download each of these packages by these `GUIDEs`.Is there such a location in the web? or is there any better solution to solve the issue?

Comment: Have to tell you that it sounds like your best bet is a full reinstall - that box is messed up. Do you see any packages to uninstall from the Add / Remove Applet available via the control panel?

Comment: for some of theme yes.but when i try to uninstall theme it fails , beside i have not idea which package should i remove.

Comment: Most becoming those winter bash glasses :-). Needs more purple though...

Comment: i am not sure its becoming but is the best among the options ;D.nevertheless purple is my favorite color specially visual studio one.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you delete the Package Cache? [**Do you have little disk space?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347375/vs-2017-installation-failed/49347648#49347648) The Visual Studio installer is so complex that you are fighting windmills trying to fix this I think. Perhaps they have an uninstall tool of some kind that will clean the slate.

Is this **Visual Studio 2017**? If so, maybe try these links:

- [**Remove Visual Studio**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2017)
- [Cleaning up corrupt Visual Studio instances](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2017/09/01/cleaning-up-corrupt-visual-studio-instances/)

I doubt it will work since you have deleted the package cache. Note that most MSI-based installers should be able to uninstall without the package cache due to the cached MSI file in the **super hidden** folder **`%SystemRoot%\Installer`**.

Whatever you do do not delete anything from **`%SystemRoot%\Installer`**. Then you are in a totally unrecoverable state since this is an internal Windows Installer implementation detail. Do not mess around in here unless you know exactly what you are doing.

The files in **`%SystemRoot%\Installer`** are used to uninstall from the Add / Remove Programs Applet.

---

***Further Links***:

- [Visual Studio 2017 Broken and Cannot Uninstall or Repair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375811/visual-studio-2017-broken-and-cannot-uninstall-or-repair)

Comment: i've deleted theme coz they eat my valuable ssd hard drive, bad luck is i've deleted content of installer folder as well.and i am not able to uninstall visual studio coz it's my exact problem ;D;

Comment: Maybe you have a backup somewhere that you did not recall at first? Otherwise I am afraid there is no way out of that corner. As a fellow deployment guy once wrote: sometimes we paint ourselves into four corners. Please check my link for tips on freeing up SSD space. Best of luck Sire, I am afraid I am out of ideas :-(.

Comment: The old msizap might work, but I would just do a rebuild. msizap was never safe and is now not supported.

Comment: thanks buddy for sticking to problem.this is really disappointing we are not able to get packages manually. nevertheless i ended up using `InstallUninstallTrubleshooter` .

Comment: Rebuild would be very advisable for something that broken. You will not be able to maintain or upgrade any applications. Zapping them will leave settings on disk and in the registry. Reinstalling on top is likely - certain even - to create unexpected errors. Sorry. Before rebuilding, please see the link with tips on using admin installs. And maybe investigate offline installation of Visual Studio? [Maybe also check this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2017/04/17/moving-or-disabling-the-package-cache-for-visual-studio-2017/).

Comment: Of course - if you rebuild - the best choice is to go for a bigger SSD at the same time, but that is just stating the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

*have deleted content of C:\ProgramData\Package Cache directory then whole setup process will be turned into a real nightmare constantly complaining about missing packages*

Had the same issue, but with vcredist files, couldn't install any drivers without running into errors and eventually couldn't install because install failed.

I found the solution elsewhere. It said to
Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed
download troubleshooter button on the link.
Run it - choose option - have problem with installing - it lists programs - choose the missing / problematic visual c++ runtimes in the list
it will run and get fixed.
Repeat for each visual c++ you having problems with. I ran the program multiple times.