# VS2017 Update does not work any more after removing C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages content

Tags: visual-studio-2017

To free up some disk space on C: I've decided to remove completely the conten of the folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages.
After doing that, I'm not more able to update to the actual release of VS2017 Community. I'm working with 15.6.1.

Using Help-> Check for Updates does not solve the problem. I've got a window popping up telling me that my current version (15.0.0.0) is up to date!

Any idea/workaround how to solve it?

Comment: Hi Andrew, during my first installation I decided to keep the cache. It was some GB! In VS Installer my VS2017 does not show up as installed

Comment: The file being exported is something like Exported-2019-04-16.vssettings with .vssettings extension. In the VS installer I can give a configuration file. But the file expected is a JSON file

Comment: Oh! Perhaps I should have made that more explicit: my intention was that any settings you'd made in VS would be saved for when you re-installed so that you wouldn't have to find them again. It was nothing to do with VS Installer.

Comment: I've also tried the file CurrentSettings.vssettings ... but the problem ist the format.  This file is XML formatted and not JSON. In my installer no VS2017 installation is recognised. I see VS 2017 as available, but if I try this option the installer says me that I can not install VS2017 because the installation path is not empty!

Comment: I'm not explaining the settings very well. The idea is to save the settings and then, when you have VS installed again, re-import them *if they have been reset*.

Comment: Perhaps one of the answers at [Visual Studio 2017 Broken and Cannot Uninstall or Repair](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43375811/1115360) will help.